# Get httprequests in html5 phonegap app (cross domain?)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a semi dynamic app in html5 w/jquerymobile, target atm. is iOS to begin with.
But the problem is that i need to contact a webservice with a (request)header paramater, and this is not doable.

My question might be very elementary, but since i'm developing in netbeans i ran into the problem of not being able to get data from crossdomain.

(Getting to the point). In phonegap/{non native "offline" apps}. How do i set the domain/is there a workaround for making http get/post requests with headerparams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Phonegap the web application will run off of the file:// protocol and is not bound by cross domain restrictions.

EDIT:
If you are using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap you will need to set `$.support.cors` and `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages` to true.

From the jQueryMobile [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html):

*Since jQuery Mobile relies on jQuery core's $.ajax() functionality, $.support.cors must be set to true to tell $.ajax to load cross-domain pages. We've heard reports that webviews on some platforms, like BlackBerry, support cross-domain loading, but that jQuery core incorrectly sets $.support.cors value to false which disables cross-domain $.ajax() requests and will cause the page or assets to fail to load.*

```
    $(document).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;       
    });
```

Comment: I have added some things I forgot about